# Magento 2.1.1: Error 500 details no longer display after the upgrade

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1.1

After I upgrade my Magento site to Magento 2.1.1, I no longer be able to see the details from any error 500 (it worked fine on 2.1). Instead it becomes just a blank page.

I check on /pub/errors/ folder and looks like there isn't anything change to the local.xml file. I also checked on /var/log folder, it doesn't seem to have anything new either.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: i would look for php error logs in php dir, many of times it tell the error and what went wrong.

Comment: Visit [Magento's dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#perms-set-two-users) and make certain that your permissions are set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or `/var/log/apache2/error.log`(these default locations).

Comment: Found the error messages in /var/log/httpd/{hostname}.errror.log file. Thank you for pointing it out.